# Qt and CUDA VIsual Profiler error in memory transfer size

Tags: qt, profiling, cuda

I've prepared a .pro file for use Qt and CUDA in a linux machine (64bits). When I run the application into the CUDA profiler, the app executes 12 times but before present the results i get the next error:

> Error in profiler data file '/home/myusername/development/qtspace/bin/temp_compute_profiler_0_0.csv' at line number 6 for column 'memory transfer size.

The main.cpp file is as simple as

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication> 
extern "C"
void runCudaPart();

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    runCudaPart();
    return 0;
}
```

The fact is that if i remove the "QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);" line the CUDA Visual Profiler works as excepted and show all the results.

I've checked that the cuda_profile.log is generated from the command line if i export the CUDA_PROFILE=1 environment variable. The comma-separated file is also generated if i export the COMPUTE_PROFILE_CSV=1 variale *but* the CUDA Visual Profiler crashes when i try to import that file.

Any hints about this issue? It seems something related to the CUDA visual Profiler application not with the code.

If you are wondering why i did a so simple main.cpp with Qt but without using Qt :P is that i would like improve the framework in the future to add a GUI.

// details of CUDA, GPU, OS, QT, and compiler versions

```
  Device"GeForce GTX 480"
  CUDA Driver Version:                           3.20
  CUDA Runtime Version:                          3.20
  CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    2.0
  OS: ubuntu 10.04 LTS
  QT_VERSION: 263682
  QT_VERSION_STR: 4.6.2
  gcc version 4.4.3
  nvcc compilation tool, release 3.2, V0.2.122
```

I've noticed that the problem is with the **QCoreApplication construct**. It does something with the arguments. If I modify the line as:

```
QCoreApplication a();
```

the Visual Profiler works as excepted. Hard to know what is happening and if this change will be a problem in the future. Any hints?

Regarding to the QCoreApplication construct the example also work if I call the cuda part before the QCoreApplication.

```
// this way the example works.
runCudaPart();
QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The application invokes a kernel launch and memory transfers. The application releases _all_ resources. The application exits normally (return cudaThreadExit()). Any hints. Thanks!

Comment: Did you check the csv file? Is it correct or corrupted? You could try opening it in Excel or something similar.

Comment: @Bart The csv file is fine. I can open it with OpenOffice Calc or any text editor. Thanks!

Comment: It's worth noting that the CUDA visual profiler is built on Qt.  Would it be possible to try with CUDA 4.0 to verify whether this still occurs?  If so, I would suggest filing an NVIDIA bug report (you'll need to join the CUDA [registered developer program](https://registration.nvidia.com/Cuda.aspx) ).

Comment: I have sent the CUDA visual profiler team a link to this issue so they can investigate.

Comment: @harrism I'm already registered but didn't think about that possibility. Thanks you for your report.

Comment: Regarding to CUDA 4.0, I can not try it at work. I'll give a try at home

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't reproduce this with CUDA 3.2 and QT4 on a 64 bit Ubuntu 10.04LTS system. I took this main:

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>

extern float cudamain();

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    float gflops = cudamain();

    return 0;
}
```

and a `cudamain()` containing this:

```
#include <assert.h>

#define blocksize 16
#define HM (4096) 
#define WM (4096) 
#define WN (4096)
#define HN WM 
#define WP WN   
#define HP HM  
#define PTH WM
#define PTW HM

__global__ void nonsquare(float*M, float*N, float*P, int uWM,int uWN)
{
    __shared__ float MS[blocksize][blocksize];
    __shared__ float NS[blocksize][blocksize];

    int tx=threadIdx.x, ty=threadIdx.y, bx=blockIdx.x, by=blockIdx.y;
    int rowM=ty+by*blocksize;
    int colN=tx+bx*blocksize;
    float Pvalue=0;

    for(int m=0; m<uWM; m+=blocksize){
        MS[ty][tx]=M[rowM*uWM+(m+tx)] ;
        NS[ty][tx]=M[colN + uWN*(m+ty)];
        __syncthreads();
        for(int k=0;k<blocksize;k++)
            Pvalue+=MS[ty][k]*NS[k][tx];
        __syncthreads();
    }
    P[rowM*WP+colN]=Pvalue;
}

inline void gpuerrorchk(cudaError_t state)
{
    assert(state == cudaSuccess);
}

float cudamain(){

    cudaEvent_t evstart, evstop;
    cudaEventCreate(&evstart);
    cudaEventCreate(&evstop);

    float*M=(float*)malloc(sizeof(float)*HM*WM);
    float*N=(float*)malloc(sizeof(float)*HN*WN);

    for(int i=0;i<WM*HM;i++)
        M[i]=(float)i;
    for(int i=0;i<WN*HN;i++)
        N[i]=(float)i;

    float*P=(float*)malloc(sizeof(float)*HP*WP);

    float *Md,*Nd,*Pd;
    gpuerrorchk( cudaMalloc((void**)&Md,HM*WM*sizeof(float)) );
    gpuerrorchk( cudaMalloc((void**)&Nd,HN*WN*sizeof(float)) );
    gpuerrorchk( cudaMalloc((void**)&Pd,HP*WP*sizeof(float)) );

    gpuerrorchk( cudaMemcpy(Md,M,HM*WM*sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice) );
    gpuerrorchk( cudaMemcpy(Nd,N,HN*WN*sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice) );

    dim3 dimBlock(blocksize,blocksize);//(tile_width , tile_width);
    dim3 dimGrid(WN/dimBlock.x,HM/dimBlock.y);//(width/tile_width , width/tile_witdh);

    gpuerrorchk( cudaEventRecord(evstart,0) );

    nonsquare<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(Md,Nd,Pd,WM, WN);
    gpuerrorchk( cudaPeekAtLastError() );

    gpuerrorchk( cudaEventRecord(evstop,0) );
    gpuerrorchk( cudaEventSynchronize(evstop) );
    float time;
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&time,evstart,evstop);

    gpuerrorchk( cudaMemcpy(P,Pd,WP*HP*sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost) );

    cudaFree(Md);
    cudaFree(Nd);
    cudaFree(Pd);

    float gflops=(2.e-6*WM*WM*WM)/(time);

    cudaThreadExit();

    return gflops;

}
```

(pay no attention to the actual code other than it doing memory transactions and running a kernel, it is nonsense otherwise).

Compiling the code like this:

```
cuda:~$ nvcc -arch=sm_20 -c -o cudamain.o cudamain.cu 
cuda:~$ g++ -o qtprob -I/usr/include/qt4 qtprob.cc cudamain.o -L $CUDA_INSTALL_PATH/lib64 -lQtCore -lcuda -lcudart
cuda:~$ ldd qtprob
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff242c8000)
        libQtCore.so.4 => /opt/cuda-3.2/computeprof/bin/libQtCore.so.4 (0x00007fbe62344000)
        libcuda.so.1 => /usr/lib/libcuda.so.1 (0x00007fbe61a3d000)
        libcudart.so.3 => /opt/cuda-3.2/lib64/libcudart.so.3 (0x00007fbe617ef000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fbe614db000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0x00007fbe61258000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fbe61040000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007fbe60cbd000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib/libz.so.1 (0x00007fbe60aa6000)
        libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fbe608a0000)
        libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fbe605c2000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib/librt.so.1 (0x00007fbe603ba000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fbe6019c000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fbe5ff98000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fbe626c0000)
        libpcre.so.3 => /lib/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007fbe5fd69000)
```

produces an executable which profiles without error as many times as I care to run it with the CUDA 3.2 release profiler.

All I can suggest is try my repro case and see whether it works or not. If it fails, then perhaps you have either a broken CUDA or QT installation. If it doesn't fail (and I suspect it won't), then you either have a problem with the way you are building the QT project or the actual CUDA code you are running itself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but sadly, it doesn't work :(. The CUDA Visual Profiler generates the same error.

Comment: OK, so that tells you that something is wrong with either your QT installation or your CUDA installation. Can you update your question with the **exact** details of CUDA, GPU, OS, QT, and compiler versions ? It will only be by a process of elimination that the root cause will be found.

Comment: Regarding to QT Version, the Qt Creator is Based on Qt 4.7.1 (64 bit). Anyway, i tried your example in the console. Thanks for your effort!

Comment: I tried your example last night at home in a 8500GT, also in linux 64 bits and CUDA 3.2 (i dont remember the driver version right now). The CUDA Visual Profiler failed again _but_ if i generate the csv file from the command-line i can import it in the Visual Profiler (this doesn't work on the GTX480 machine).

Comment: I've update CUDA to 4.0 at home and your example still fails :( I dont know why, but libcuda.so.1 points to /usr/lib/nvidia-current/libcuda.so.1 instead of /usr/lib. Any hints?. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you do not have multiple versions of CUDA installed? Are you using the Ubuntu packaged drivers or installing from original NVIDIA sh file? The fact that I can't reproduce this using an identical distro and the original NVIDIA drivers and distro tells me you have installation or set up problems.

Comment: I've both CUDA 3.2 and 4.0 installed and the last driver installed as a package. I switch versions to make tests. I've updated the question with the last tests. Many thanks.

Comment: You are probably true and I've a mix of libs and dependencies at home. I've also the same problem at work so i dont know what's happening. Thanks you for your efforts

Comment: I'll assume a broken CUDA or QT installation at home. Thanks you all!

Answer (score 2):

@pQB 
Hello, I am Ramesh from NVIDIA. We could not reproduce this issue locally here. This kind of error comes when the value for that column is either empty or invalid. In your case (Error in profiler data file '/home/myusername/development/qtspace/bin/temp_compute_profiler_0_0.csv' at line number 6 for column 'memory transfer size) the value for column ‘memory transfer size’ is either empty or invalid for line no. 6 in the csv file.

Can you send ‘temp_compute_profiler_0_0.csv’ if it is present in you working directory and the csv generated by command line profiler. If it is not possible check what value you getting for that column (memory transfer size) in line no. 6.

Are you running your app with default settings in Visual Profiler? Can you try running your app disabling 'memory transfer size' option? To disable this option click menu “Session->Session Settings…”, on session settings dialog click “Other Options” tab, uncheck “memory transfer size”

Comment: I run all the test with default settings in Visual Profiler. The Visual Profiler deletes the file temp_compute_profiler_0_0.csv after the error message. Only files from 1_0.csv to 11_0.csv remain in the working directory after the the error. Disabling the 'memory transfer size' option still generate the error. I can safe that file before 'accept' the error message :).

Comment: The column memtransfersize is empry and is a method: memcpyHtoA. The file generated from the command-line is simpler than the Visual Profiler one. What email can i use to send you both, the Visual Profiler and command-line files?

Comment: @pQB You can use 'rgunjal@nvidia.com' to share your files